# draw x tick labels on the top layer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For a group of plots i want to place all x tick labels on the top layer so that lines, that have been drawn at the end of the tikzpicture environment, are on a layer below the labels.

I already tried to set the layer with `on top layer` but unfortunately a `scope` environment seems to be always needed to draw on a specific layer.

My example below illustrates the problem. The goal is that the x tick label node at x=2 is eventually placed on top of the dashed line.

---

**Example**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-layers}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \begin{groupplot}[
        no markers,
        xmax=6,
        ymin=0,
        every x tick label/.style={
            fill=red
        },
        group style = {
            group size = 1 by 2,
        },
    ]

        \nextgroupplot[ymax=15]
            \addplot +[domain=0:6] {0.5*x^2};
            \coordinate (t1g1-top) at (axis cs:2,15);
            \coordinate (t1g1-bottom) at (axis cs:2,0);

        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot  +[domain=0:6] {x};
            \coordinate (t1g2-bottom) at (axis cs:2,0);

    \end{groupplot}


    \begin{scope}[on above layer]
        \draw[dashed, ultra thick] (t1g1-top) -- (t1g2-bottom);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do it with only a minor side effect is to use the `set layers` option in combination with `axis on top` to achieve what you want. Both options should be added to the `axis` options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % activate layers
        set layers,
        % and draw axis lines and labels on "top layers"
        axis on top,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        no markers,
        xmax=6,
        ymin=0,
        every x tick label/.style={
            fill=red
        },
        group style = {
            group size = 1 by 2,
        },
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[ymax=15]
        \addplot+ [domain=0:6] {0.5*x^2};
        \coordinate (t1g1-top) at (axis cs:2,15);
    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot+ [domain=0:6] {x};
        \coordinate (t1g2-bottom) at (axis cs:2,0);
    \end{groupplot}

        \draw[dashed, ultra thick] (t1g1-top) -- (t1g2-bottom);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: How can one set the axis ticks (not labels) to be "on top"? Or even one specific tick? Any ideas (without changing anything else about the axis or tick labels)? For example, with a line parallel to the *x*-axis, a specific *y*-axis tick might be covered.

Comment: I have asked a question to that effect here: [How to change a specific set of axis ticks to be “on top” without changing axis or grid lines (pgfplots)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585277/116907).