# How to change a specific set of axis ticks to be “on top” without changing axis or grid lines (pgfplots)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have drawn a Cartesian coordinate plane with `pgfplots`, and added a line *y* = 1 in red.

<kbd>[image: not zoomed]
not zoomed
example of output</kbd>
<kbd>[image: zoomed]
zoomed
example of output</kbd>

The *y*-axis tick at *y* = 1 is covered up by the red line.

---

I would like to

- draw the specific *y* = 1 axis **tick** on top of the red line
- **without** changing anything else (not the red line, not the axis, not the grid, not other ticks, not axis labels, etc.) For instance, the red line should otherwise be on top of the axis itself, and be on top of the grid lines.

More generally, it would be nice to add something like

`yaxis ticks on top={<list of ticks to be on top>}`

and similarly for the other axis. Can this be done?

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor} %here only to make a custom colour


\newcommand{\size}{2}
\colorlet{verylightgray}{lightgray!35} %making a new colour, verylightgray


\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, xlabel={$x$}, xlabel style={anchor=north east}, ylabel={$y$}, ylabel style={anchor=north east}, axis equal image, yticklabel style={anchor=south}, grid style={thin, verylightgray}}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[my style,
            xmin=-\size, xmax=\size, ymin=-\size, ymax=\size,
            xtick={-\size,-\size+1,...,\size}, ytick={-\size,-\size+1,...,\size},
            xticklabels={}, yticklabels={},
            grid=major
        ]

        \draw[thick, red] (axis cs: -3,1) -- (axis cs: 3,1); %here is the red line
        
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried to write `axis on top` on the axis environment options? I think that's what you want (?)

Comment: @Jes Yes, I have tried. This changes more things then I'd like. For example, it adds the grid line on top of the red line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK27W.png.

Comment: Cristmas, then the only way I can think of is to manually set up the `ytick`, so there is not a tick at the line y= 1, in combination with the option `axis on top`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is the solution if only specific ticks should be shown on top.
(As already stated in the comments below another answer, one should have a really, really good point why to do this.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \newcommand{\size}{2}
    \colorlet{verylightgray}{lightgray!35} %making a new colour, verylightgray
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.17,
        my style/.append style={
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % added stuff
            set layers,
            extra tick style={
                tick style={
                    % this should do the trick ...
                    /pgfplots/on layer=axis descriptions,
                    % ... but in case it is not "high" enough use this
%                    /pgfplots/on layer=axis foreground,
                },
                yticklabels={},
                grid=none, % <- this prevents new grid lines from being added when special ticks are introduced
            },
            extra y ticks={1},
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            xlabel style={anchor=north east},
            ylabel={$y$},
            ylabel style={anchor=north east},
            axis equal image,
            yticklabel style={anchor=south},
            grid style={thin, verylightgray},
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my style,
        xmin=-\size, xmax=\size, ymin=-\size, ymax=\size,
        xtick={-\size,-\size+1,...,\size}, ytick={-\size,-\size+1,...,\size},
        xticklabels={}, yticklabels={},
        grid=major,
    ]
        \draw [thick, red] (axis cs: -3,1) -- (axis cs: 3,1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing a zoomed result of above code]

Comment: First impressions based on picture: great job! Hopefully I can test it more thoroughly soon. In the meanwhile, +1 and thank you! I will also try to compare this solution with my original MWE to understand exactly what you changed to make it work :)

Comment: How may one generalise this answer for ticks on the *x*-axis? For example, say there is a vertical green line at x = -1. The naive approach of similarly adding ``xticklabels={},`` and ``extra x ticks={-1},`` does not seem to work.

Comment: In a test I did exactly this and is works as expected ...

Comment: 1. Thank you for responding. You are correct, I had forgot to add one comma which is why it did not work. 2. Is there way to also bring a specific label on top of the green line (irrespective of, so with or without, the tick)? For example, if there were a green vertical line at x = –1 and a label directly below an ``extra x tick`` at x = –1, how would one achieve this? I tried [this approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGJX3.png) but it did not work.

Comment: It seems so that you have the `extra tick style` twice in your code. Using this syntax means that the second style is *appended* to the first style and in the first style it is given that labels should not be shown. So try commenting the first `extra tick style` (not tested).

Comment: The second one is ``extra label style``. Or did you have something else in mind by saying "twice in your code"?

Comment: You are right, it *is* written `extra label style`. But I can't find this in the documentation. So either this is an undocumented feature or you are ignoring an error message (in the LOG file) ... If you want extra ticks to have labels, simply comment `yticklabels={}` (and friends) which will give you the default labels, i.e. the corresponding numeric value.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more explicit: I made a shot-in-the-dark *guess* of what the syntax would be :) (multiple errors popped up). If I try to add the labels (in the way you suggest) or in similar ways, then the output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi0fK.png). I.e. the green line goes over the tick label at x = –1. I haven't so far been able to modify your answer to bring the tick label x = –1 on top of the green line. Of course, changing the position of the tick might be possible (/ adding bit more whitespace between the minus – and 1, in this case), but that's another matter.

Comment: Should I perhaps ask a new question to that effect? It is not, strictly speaking, part of the OP here. By the way, I finised testing the solution you presented in this answer. And it does indeed work nicely. I will accept it soon, and probably award the bounty. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You are welcome. In fact you should be able from this answer to know what has to be done to also bring up the `ticklabels` over/on top of the "green line". You only have to find the corresponding `style`. (Maybe as an additional hint: It should already be present in the code you provided. (The "should" is because I didn't test it, but I am pretty sure.)) If not, it is a good idea to ask a [follow-up questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117). Good luck!

Comment: I must also thank you for encouraging me to try to solve the tick label thing "semi-independently". By trying various things and syntax, [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJNjK.png) seems to work nicely!

Comment: Congratulations. And great that you were willing to invest some time to solve the problem yourself with some help. That is how you really learn whatever. Then helping is fun (at least for me). I like that much more then simply producing a "requested" image. Because OP then does learn that much if anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

So this is what you are searching for with the new requirements?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \newcommand{\size}{2}
    \colorlet{verylightgray}{lightgray!35} %making a new colour, verylightgray
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.17,
        % based on `axis on top`
        /pgfplots/layers/my axis on top/.define layer set={
            axis background,
            axis grid,              % <-- moved here
            pre main,
            main,
%            axis grid,
            axis ticks,
            axis lines,
            axis tick labels,
            axis descriptions,
            axis foreground,
        }{
            /pgfplots/layers/standard
        },
        my style/.append style={
            % set the newly add layer set
            set layers=my axis on top,  % <-- added
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            xlabel style={anchor=north east},
            ylabel={$y$},
            ylabel style={anchor=north east},
            axis equal image,
            yticklabel style={anchor=south},
            grid style={thin, verylightgray},
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my style,
        xmin=-\size, xmax=\size, ymin=-\size, ymax=\size,
        xtick={-\size,-\size+1,...,\size}, ytick={-\size,-\size+1,...,\size},
        xticklabels={}, yticklabels={},
        grid=major,
    ]
        \draw [thick, red] (axis cs: -3,1) -- (axis cs: 3,1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing a zoomed result from the above code]

Comment: Thank you, I will test in a minute. However, please note that there are no "new requirements". Every requirement that exists currently was already in the original post. (See edits which only added emphasis like boldface and caps; or additional example).

Comment: As you can see currently the black axis line is still on top of the red line. Is you really want to have your solution this would mean, that either *all* tick lines are on top of the axis line as well or you really, really only want the *one* tick for `y=1` on top of "everything", which of course would be inconsistent to the rest.

Comment: Besides that, if this really is what you want, I don't see *why* this should be needed. You should have a really good point for that. If so, maybe you should tell us this point and maybe we can provide an alternative or even better way to reach that goal.

Comment: You are right, the axis line is still on top of the red line in the solution you posted. This is not ideal but is already very good (since the tick is visible,+1). On the topic of "one tick" vs. "all ticks": in the plot I actually needed it was only relevant to change the appearance of the tick at y = 1. Actually, I do not mind if the all other ticks are brought to the foreground as well. However, I chose to formulate the question as "How to change **a specific set** of axis ticks" because *maybe* someone in the future needed that solution. So to summarise: to be most flexible for others, too.

Answer (score 1):

I present two similar solutions below. Both have to do with layers.

- In the "simple" solution you load `set layers` and then can assign the layer where you want to have what using the `on layer` feature.
- In the "bit more complicated" solution we define a new layer set based on the `standard` layers set. In that we move the `axis lines` layer (somewhere) after the `main` layer. Last we load that layer set with `set layers`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \newcommand{\size}{2}
    \colorlet{verylightgray}{lightgray!35} %making a new colour, verylightgray
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.17,
        /pgfplots/layers/my axis on top/.define layer set={
            axis background,
            axis grid,
            axis ticks,
%            axis lines,
            axis tick labels,
            pre main,
            main,
            axis lines,             % <-- moved here
            axis descriptions,
            axis foreground,
        }{
            /pgfplots/layers/standard
        },
        my style/.append style={
%            % "simple" solution just requires to `set layers`
%            set layers,
            % bit more complicated solution requires to also set the newly add layer set
            set layers=my axis on top,  % <-- added
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            xlabel style={anchor=north east},
            ylabel={$y$},
            ylabel style={anchor=north east},
            axis equal image,
            yticklabel style={anchor=south},
            grid style={thin, verylightgray},
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my style,
        xmin=-\size, xmax=\size, ymin=-\size, ymax=\size,
        xtick={-\size,-\size+1,...,\size}, ytick={-\size,-\size+1,...,\size},
        xticklabels={}, yticklabels={},
        grid=major,
    ]
        % "simple" solution
        \addplot+ [
            orange,
            % state the layer where you want to have the line
            on layer={axis background},
        ] coordinates {
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0.5)
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0.5)
        };

        \draw [thick, red] (axis cs: -3,1) -- (axis cs: 3,1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Apologies for my extreme delay in responding. But aren't the axis ticks still covered up (missing)? I don't mind per se if the graph goes over the axis themselves; but I wished to display the axis *ticks* on top of the graph. The orange line has the issue that the grid lines run over the graph.

Comment: I have decided to offer a small bounty of 100 for a canonical answer. This is especially necessary (more coverage) since I was absent for a few months, and that was my fault.